# Running Ruby gem on specific platforms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, unicorn

Is there logic I can add to a Ruby gem so that it won't bundle when running on Windows? I'm working on a project with the unicorn gem and I want to leave it in the gemfile but ignore it when running the server on Windows OS.

Comment: Maybe this could be done by: defining an new environment in the Gemfile, adding the gem to only that environment, setting the server in question to run as that environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude it from windows, you basically have to whitelist platforms. I usually use:

```
gem 'my_gem' , '~> 1.2.3' , :platforms => [ :ruby ]
```

If you are using jruby, or something you may need to alter it from [this list](http://bundler.io/v1.2/man/gemfile.5.html) of available formats:

```
ruby
    C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
ruby_18
    ruby AND version 1.8
ruby_19
    ruby AND version 1.9
mri
    Same as ruby, but not Rubinius
mri_18
    mri AND version 1.8
mri_19
    mri AND version 1.9
rbx
    Same as ruby, but only Rubinius (not MRI)
jruby
    JRuby
mswin
    Windows
mingw
    Windows 'mingw32' platform (aka RubyInstaller)
mingw_18
    mingw AND version 1.8
mingw_19
    mingw AND version 1.9
```